# get current location and then refreshing map

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to know how can I refresh the map and place markers after calculating the current position in the onCreate method of an activity.

I know how to get the current location, but I don't know if I need to use any specific event after that to refresh the map.

My algorithm is this:

1. Get the current location (done).
2. Send request to back-end with that location.
3. Placing the markers for the points returned by the back-end.

Of course, I know how to deal with steps 2 and 3, what I'm asking is about where to put that code for that steps (I guess not in onCreate method)

thanks!!!

Comment: it doesn't work because when it enters onResume(), it hasn't got the current location yet. I think it is a matter of synchronous task.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend can populate a inmemory arraylist of geopoints. Or you can populate sharedpreferences with the list of points. Once your activity is alive again, you can retrieve all the geopoints in your `onResume`.

Your backend request I am sure is a  async task. On the `onPostExecute` you can send out a intent to a new activity, in that case you can do it on onCreate.